# Set colour and scale of legend

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to set the legend scale of my plot between 0 and 1. I got fade colour plot when I add `limits= c(0,1)` to `scale_fill_continuous`. However, when this part is removed, the colour of the plot are ok but not set scale.

Here is a producible code:

```
# Create some sample data
CNP <- rnorm(48,0.4/2,0.4/6)       
Nrings <-2 # Number of rings
Nsectors<-24 # Number of sectors
day=seq(0,24*Nrings-1,by=1)
d5 <- data.frame(day,CNP)
# remove period from time coordinate
d5$x <- d5$day %% (Nsectors) +1 
# compute number of periods elapsed
d5$y <-rep(0.76,2*24) 
# to match the size of macular shots and the grid
d5$y[25:48] <-2.1

require(ggplot2)
### The plot with `limits=c(0,1)`
ggplot(d5) + 
     geom_tile(aes(x=x, y=y, fill=CNP)) +
     scale_fill_continuous(low="white", high="darkgreen",space = "rgb",na.value="grey90", limits=c(0,1)) +
     theme(axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),axis.text.y=element_blank())
```

Any suggestions to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rescale your fill variable to the range [0, 1] first:

```
library(dplyr); library(scales)

ggplot(d5 %>% mutate(CNP = rescale(CNP)))+
  geom_tile(aes(x=x, y=y, fill=CNP)) +
  scale_fill_continuous(low="white", high="darkgreen",
                        na.value="grey90")+
  theme(axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),axis.text.y=element_blank())
```

[image]